# Travel to Hawaii for first time from Kansas, USA

Tags: usa, air-travel, money, hawaii

I am living in Kansas city. I have only heard about Hawaii, never actually went there. Planning a vacation for 3-4 weeks. I want to experience all the best things about Hawaii. I don't care what other people say on Internet, I want to know from someone who lives in Hawaii or have been to Hawaii (and loves travelling). I have following questions:

- Which islands to visit? I have searched for [list of islands in hawaii](https://www.google.com/search?q=list+of+islands+in+hawaii&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS752US752&oq=list+of+islands+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.9431j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) Which ones are the best islands to visit.
- What are the means of commute between islands. Is it only by air or by water can be good experience/cheaper?
- Airlines ticket are very expensive. Which time of year can I find an offer or cheaper fair?

Comment: Welcome to TSE! Unfortunately, your question is far, far too broad to be answerable in our Q&A format. At this stage of planning, you should be reading guidebooks and visiting sites like WikiVoyage and TripAdvisor to get a sense of the place and all that the various islands offer, and to answer the basics. For example, there are no ferries between islands and therefore no way to "commute" by water. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: @choster, I am very specific with my question. I have bullet pointed my questions. I don't understand how is that far broad? Do you mean I need to post each questions separately?

Comment: Question 1 is a question with an almost entirely subjective answer. Questions with almost entirely subjective answers can't be answered on this site since almost any answer could be valid. Questions 2 and 3 should each be asked as separate questions.

Comment: "I don't care what other people say on Internet". You realize this is part of the internet?

Comment: I feel like I have posted this on English Language group and not Travel group. Everybody is telling me what I have written instead of answering me the question. If none of you have the answer and just want to discuss my English then I can delete the question.

Comment: @Devang please see the comment by Jacob Horbulyk regarding the content of your question.  I agree Question 1 is very broad, the other two should be separate questions.

Comment: Right now, the answer to Question 1 is "All of them (that you legally can)!" This is because "best" depends on what you want to do, what you're interested in, how much money you have to spend, and a lot of other factors. One person's "best" will be another person's "worst". I've been to five of the six publicly accessible islands, and all have reasons to recommend them. I have no idea which to suggest for you based on your current question.

Comment: To All Commentators, please see the answer below. That was the answer i was looking for. Not the comments to make my English correct or understanding concept of Internet. All I wanted was suggestion. I thought this was discussion forum and user can ask anything he wants. My question  got answered that's all I wanted, I don't care you guys put my question "on Hold" or "delete" it. But this question and Tom's answer is going to help people in Future. **Go ahead comment on that**
Thank you Tom, for your answer, you were great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have four weeks, plan a week on each of the four majors (Kauai, Oahu, Maui, Hawai'i).  Each has a different character and different aspects to check out.  And each has both local side and touristy side, I prefer local style, staying in small towns away from the beach resorts and dining at the drive in.

Inter-island travel is pretty much by air.  There has been talk of ferries, but nothing much seems to come of it.  You can go by ferry from Maui to Molokai and Lanai, but that is about it.

Hawaii has high and shoulder seasons, no low season.  Spring and fall are shoulder seasons, so you may find better hotel prices and possibly lower airfares.  But really killer deal airfares are rare.

Unfortunately "best" is so subjective and what I might like having lived there will be different than what you might like as a casual visitor (example, would you order spam at breakfast?  that's local style and something I enjoy).

Comment: @Devang - You might join the TripAdvisor Hawaii forums for more info.  Their format is better suited for opinionated queries, ie best places to stay, best places to eat, best things to do, etc